# Trying to get PHP streams working with Thawte TLS RSA CA G1 - internal error

Tags: php, ssl

I try to get PHP accepting the a certificate which Chrome accepts.

I created the following minimal reproducing example:

```
echo OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $fetch = new \ParagonIE\Certainty\RemoteFetch('/tmp/');
    $latestBundle = $fetch->getLatestBundle();

    $context = stream_context_create(
        [
            'ssl' => array(
                'cafile' => $latestBundle->getFilePath(),
                'SNI_enabled' => true,
            )
        ]
    );

$url = 'https://example.com:8080/x/y';

    echo file_get_contents($url  . '?wsdl', false, $context);
```

I am using https://github.com/paragonie/certainty to get the latest CAcerts.

I get the following error

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): 
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert 
internal error in /tmp/test/test.php on line 20
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in 
/tmp/test/test.php on line 20
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://example.com:8080/x/y? 
wsdl): failed to open stream: operation failed in 
/tmp/test/test.php on line 20
```

What is going wrong here?

Unfortunately I cannot share the URL (it's behind a Firewall anyways).

Accessing it with curl --insecure works - but I would really like to properly verify the CA cert

*EDIT* 
SSLyze outputs this:

```
 SCAN RESULTS FOR example.COM:8080 - >
 ------------------------------------------------------

 * TLSV1_1 Cipher Suites:
       Forward Secrecy                    OK - Supported
       RC4                                OK - Not Supported

     Preferred:
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                 256 bits                                                                  
     Accepted:
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                     256 bits                                                                  
        TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                 ANONYMOUS                                                                 
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                 256 bits                                                                  
     Undefined - An unexpected error happened:
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                  OpenSSLError - error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error


 * TLSV1 Cipher Suites:
       Forward Secrecy                    OK - Supported
       RC4                                OK - Not Supported

     Preferred:
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                 256 bits                                                                  
     Accepted:
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                     256 bits                                                                  
        TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                 ANONYMOUS                                                                 
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                 256 bits                                                                  
     Undefined - An unexpected error happened:
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                  OpenSSLError - error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error


 * Deflate Compression:
                                          OK - Compression disabled

 * Certificate Information:
     Content
       SHA1 Fingerprint:                  c2b3ce5b0905caa2ec5998aacf074f99cffb0207
       Common Name:                       example.com
       Issuer:                            Thawte TLS RSA CA G1
       Serial Number:                     10361996092389695445524615643169842847
       Not Before:                        2018-12-05 00:00:00
       Not After:                         2020-12-04 12:00:00
       Signature Algorithm:               sha256
       Public Key Algorithm:              RSA
       Key Size:                          2048
       Exponent:                          65537 (0x10001)
       DNS Subject Alternative Names:     ['example.com']

     Trust
       Hostname Validation:               OK - Certificate matches example.com
       Android CA Store (9.0.0_r3):       FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: unable to get local issuer certificate
       iOS CA Store (11):                 FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: unable to get local issuer certificate
       Java CA Store (jre-10.0.2):        FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: unable to get local issuer certificate
       macOS CA Store (High Sierra):      FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: unable to get local issuer certificate
       Mozilla CA Store (2018-08-23):     FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: unable to get local issuer certificate
       Windows CA Store (2018-08-04):     FAILED - Certificate is NOT Trusted: unable to get local issuer certificate
       Symantec 2018 Deprecation:         OK - Not a Symantec-issued certificate
       Received Chain:                    example.com
       Verified Chain:                    ERROR - Could not build verified chain (certificate untrusted?)
       Received Chain Contains Anchor:    ERROR - Could not build verified chain (certificate untrusted?)
       Received Chain Order:              OK - Order is valid
       Verified Chain contains SHA1:      ERROR - Could not build verified chain (certificate untrusted?)

     Extensions
       OCSP Must-Staple:                  NOT SUPPORTED - Extension not found
       Certificate Transparency:          OK - 3 SCTs included

     OCSP Stapling
                                          NOT SUPPORTED - Server did not send back an OCSP response

 * OpenSSL CCS Injection:
                                          OK - Not vulnerable to OpenSSL CCS injection

 * SSLV3 Cipher Suites:
      Server rejected all cipher suites.

 * SSLV2 Cipher Suites:
      Server rejected all cipher suites.

 * Resumption Support:
      With Session IDs:                  OK - Supported (5 successful, 0 failed, 0 errors, 5 total attempts).
      With TLS Tickets:                  NOT SUPPORTED - TLS ticket not assigned.

 * Downgrade Attacks:
       TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV:                 VULNERABLE - Signaling cipher suite not supported

 * TLSV1_3 Cipher Suites:
      Server rejected all cipher suites.

 * OpenSSL Heartbleed:
                                          OK - Not vulnerable to Heartbleed

 * TLSV1_2 Cipher Suites:
       Forward Secrecy                    OK - Supported
       RC4                                OK - Not Supported

     Preferred:
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                     256 bits                                                                  
     Accepted:
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                     256 bits                                                                  
        TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                 ANONYMOUS                                                                 
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                                 256 bits                                                                  
     Undefined - An unexpected error happened:
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                  OpenSSLError - error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error


 * Session Renegotiation:
       Client-initiated Renegotiation:    VULNERABLE - Server honors client-initiated renegotiations
       Secure Renegotiation:              OK - Supported

 * ROBOT Attack:
                                          OK - Not vulnerable


 SCAN COMPLETED IN 9.31 S
```

Answer (score 0):

The internal error is resolved like this:

```
    $context = stream_context_create(
        [
            'ssl' => array(
                    'cafile' => $latestBundle->getFilePath(),
                    'SNI_enabled' => true,
                    'ciphers' => 'HIGH:TLSv1.2:TLSv1.1:TLSv1.0:SSLv3:SSLv2',
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'crypto_disable_compression' => true,
                    'method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
                    'verify_depth' => 10,
            )
        ]
    );
```

But still I cannot verify the CA cert.

In Chrome it works fine.

This is because Chrome does some workarounds, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199963/certificate-works-in-chrome-firefox-but-not-with-curl-unable-to-get-local-is

So I have to wait until the chain is configured properly.